# Java - Spring AOP on Eclipse?

Tags: java, spring, plugins, jar, aspectj

I need to use AOP of Spring in Eclipse. So I tried to use '@Aspect' annotation, but it does not found it and just suggest me to create myself. As I understand Spring itself does not have this annotation? Because in documentation it shows that is uses aspectj. So I downloaded from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/aspectj/aspectj-1.7.4.jar

Then added it as external jar from project properties. But still nothing changed. Did I miss something?

Update:

I also installed AJDT via plugin manager, but still it does not recognize '@Aspect' annotation. So what should I do so it would recognize it?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you need both the aspectj plugin and the spring aspect plugins.
First, make sure you have the proper maven dependencies in your project. It should be:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

And modify the versions by the ones you would like to use.
Then if you use a maven plugin for Eclipse like m2e it should find the dependencies.

Hope that helps

Comment: It seems I needed to create aspectj project. But the problem now is, every time I save anything in project it starts building workspace and it takes ages for Eclipse to do it. And my code is a mere few lines. I don't get it why it is so slow?

Comment: Are you using Maven? If so then look up on Maven indexing and how to disable it, there are loads of options to disable features you don't need and Maven Nexus indexer could be the cause.